# merging some accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I just created an account I can log into:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462529/user1462529

But my orphaned account that I can no longer log into is:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084580/bsb

And I also have a question, under a since deleted user
(while thrashing around between accounts and machines):

[Non-destructive Git checkout in dirty work tree ($HOME/.dotfiles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258988/non-destructive-git-checkout-in-dirty-work-tree-home-dotfiles)

user1348253

Could I please get these merged?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084580/bsb

That's an unregistered account. If you recall the email address you used for it, you can recover access to it here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Then send an email to the "contact us" address at the bottom of every page, and we'll get you fixed up.

Meanwhile, I'll check on that other question for you.